# How can I duplicate a row in a Word table?

Tags: vba, office-interop, ms-word, office-2010

I am trying to duplicate a table row in Word, using VBA, **without using the Selection object or the clipboard**. That is, I want a new row that has the same content as an existing row.

To do this, I first create a new (empty) row, and loop through each cell in the source row and copy its contents into the corresponding cell in the target row.

To copy each cell, I get a `Range` object that references the entire content of the source cell, and an equivalent `Range` for the target cell, and then do this:

```
oToRange.FormattedText = oFromRange.FormattedText
```

This works well on Office 2003, and also works most of the time on Office 2010. However, I am having a real problem with one particular scenario. I have (greatly) simplified that scenario to demonstrate the core of the problem.

In the picture below, there are two cells in the outer (grey) 2R x 1C table. The second row is the row to be copied. The first row is the new row I created, and into which I want to copy the content of the second row.

[image]

You'll notice that the second row contains a nested table.

When I run the code below in Word 2003, it works perfectly, and I get the following result:

[image]

But, in Word 2010, the same code produces this result:

[image]

As you can see, the cell content has been inserted *before* (and outside) the target table cell.

It's worth mentioning that if I put something after the nested table, so that it's no longer the last thing in the source cell, then this problem does not occur.

Here's the full VBA code I'm using:

```
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oDoc = ThisDocument

Dim oFromRange As Range
Set oFromRange = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range
oFromRange.End = oFromRange.End - 1

Dim oToRange As Range
Set oToRange = ThisDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
oToRange.End = oToRange.End - 1

oToRange.FormattedText = oFromRange.FormattedText
```

*NOTE: the adjustment to the end of the source and target ranges is necessary because `Cell.Range` includes the end-of-cell marker, and I don't want to copy that.*

**What can I do to persuade it to put the content *inside* the target cell (like Word 2003 does), rather than before it?**

Comment: + 1 for a well explained question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope I have understood your query correctly... Isn't this what you are trying to do? This code will copy Row 1 of the table and create a copy of that row below it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Table

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    tbl.Rows(1).Range.Copy
    tbl.Rows(1).Select
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow
    tbl.Rows(2).Range.Paste
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**FOLLOWUP** (From Comments)

This code doesn't use the `Selection` object

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rowNew As Row

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set rowNew = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(1))
    tbl.Rows(2).Range.Copy
    tbl.Rows(1).Range.Paste
End Sub
```

**MORE FOLLOWUP** (From Comments)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rowNew As Row

    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set rowNew = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(1))
    tbl.Rows(1).Range.FormattedText = tbl.Rows(2).Range.FormattedText
    '~~~> This is required as the above code inserts a blank row in between
    tbl.Rows(2).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I should have said in the question that I don't want to use the `Selection` object. I have thousands of lines of code that deliberately avoids doing that, and I'm not keen to make an exception here. It must be possible to achieve the same result without it?

Comment: Yup it is possible :) Updated the above post

Comment: Aaargh. I'm embarrassed to complain again, but I also don't want to use the clipboard. I had put this in the update at the top of my question, but I forgot to also put it in my comment. Sorry, I've wasted your time here, twice, and I humbly apologise for that.

Comment: No worries. You are helping me think of different possibilities ;) Try the above updated code

Comment: Genius! That does indeed seem to do the trick. Thanks very much!

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I am receiving below error: cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells. any suggestion?

Comment: @rima: I would recommend asking a new question with a link to this question. Also include the structure of the table in your question. And most important, include the code that you tried to solve the issue. We will then take it from there :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Function duplicate_row(ByRef ontable, rownnumber) As Row
 Dim c
 Dim fromrow As Row
 Dim newrow As Row
 Set fromrow = ontable.Rows(rownnumber)
 Set newrow = ontable.Rows.Add
 newrow.Range.FormattedText = fromrow.Range.FormattedText
 ontable.Rows(ontable.Rows.Count).Delete
 Set duplicate_row = newrow
End Function



Sub test()
 Dim newrow As Row

 Set newrow = duplicate_row(ActiveDocument.Tables(1), 2)
 newrow.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="text_service", ReplaceWith:="aaa", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 newrow.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="text_amount", ReplaceWith:="500", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 newrow.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="text_price", ReplaceWith:="50", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 newrow.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="text_comment", ReplaceWith:="bbb", Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Delete ' after adding all rows, delete the tempalte row
End Sub
```

Comment: How does this differ from the last version in the accepted answer?

Comment: not differes its a function which makes it useful. it adds lines after template in order

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what I think is the simplest solution. Doesn't use the selection object or clipboard and doesn't create an extra row that needs to be deleted.

```
Sub DuplicateRow(t As Table, r As Integer)
    t.Rows(r).Range.Next.InsertBefore vbCr
    t.Rows(r).Range.Next.FormattedText = t.Rows(r).Range.FormattedText
End Sub
```

Just call the macro with the table and the row index to duplicate. Works with any row within the table (first, last or anything in-between)

```
DuplicateRow ActiveDocument.Tables(1), 2
```